# SQLite Prepared Statements not Inserting

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

I'm trying to insert into a database using PDO but after finishing the script and testing it out and I am not seeing any sort of input from inserting into the database, I've tried returning errors from PDO but nothing. I'm not sure what's happening

I've updated the parameter names and they do not seem to change anything with the result of the code. Seems the q() function is just having issues.

Database is initialized and looks like:

```
    function __construct() {
        if ( ! file_exists( dbpath . DB ) ) {
            $this->db = true;
            $this->open( dbpath . DB, SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE ) or $this->db = false;
            if ( $this->db == false ) {
                return false;
            }
            $table = "CREATE TABLE link_hits( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, link TEXT NOT NULL, hits INT NOT NULL, date_added datetime default current_timestamp)";     
            $this->exec($table);
        } else { 
            $this->db = true;
            $this->open( dbpath . DB, SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE ) or $this->db = false;
            if ( $this->db == false ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Prepared statement function

```
    function q ( $q, $v ) {
        if ( $this->db ) {
            $this->securedb = $this->prepare( $q );
            foreach ( $v as $k=>$vv ) {
                if ( is_numeric( $vv ) ) {
                    $this->securedb->bindValue($k, $vv, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                } else {
                    $this->securedb->bindValue($k, $vv, SQLITE3_TEXT);
                }
            }
            $this->errorInfo = $this->errorInfo();
            return ( ( $this->handle = $this->execute() ) == true ) ? $this->handle : false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Add link function

```
    function addlink ( $link ) {

        if ( $this->linkexists( $link ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->que = "INSERT INTO link_hits (link, hits) VALUES (:link, :hits)";
        $this->input = array(
                            ':link' => $link,
                            ':hits' => 0
                             );
        return ( $this->q( $this->que, $this->input ) ) ? true : false;

    }
```

Am I not forming my statement correctly? I followed several tutorials. I'm really used to MySQL but will not have access to it where this will be. :(

Even my linkexists function throws a false. And yes, the link is there, I forced it in with a normal query.

```
    function linkexists( $link ) {

        $this->que = "SELECT link FROM link_hits WHERE type='table' AND link=':link'";
        $this->input = array(
                    ':link' => $link
                );
        return ( ( $this->handle = $this->q( $this->que, $this->input ) ) == true ) ? true : false;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you appending a `;` next to your binding variables ?

Comment: Saw it in a few examples. It's just a pattern anything could be used IE *{|}*key;:; ... at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: In `linkexists` the statement has to many quotes; PDO will insert these automatically. Try this:

`SELECT link FROM link_hits WHERE type=:type AND link=:link` - but for your main problem I have no clue. :)

Comment: Thanks, but it still throws the same error. And it's redundant either way. Even PDO documentation for checking if tables exists uses this markup, semiquotes included.

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter names](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) must not end with a semicolon:

```
$this->que = "INSERT ... VALUES (:link, :hits)";
```

Comment: I have changed the parameters, but still same scenario. Even my linkexiss throws a false.